# Error: "keypath objectID not found in entity"

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I get this error:
`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath objectID not found in entity <NSSQLEntity Pair id=2>'`

when I use "objectId" as both a search descriptor and sectionNameKeyPath for the NSFetchedResultsController.

I want each object to result in a new section.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"objectID" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"objectID" cacheName:nil];
aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;
```

Any tips?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because objectId and objectID are different strings. Check that.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same error. The cause was that I was creating temporary `NSManagedObjectContext` instance without retaining it. Simple creating the object and assigning it's reference to a variable fixed the issue in my case.